# Lists of lists to csv?

Tags: python, csv, text

I have encountered a problem with the csv module of Python.
Indeed, I have of a corpus of text. I have transformed it in what looks like a list of lists. For instance, my data looks like this

```
data = ["Hello", "how", "are", "you"]
["Fine", "and" ,"you"]
```

I want to export data to a csv file or to a text file.

HOWEVER when I use the .writerow() method of the csv module it will return ONLY one list of the corpus and I don't understand why (It is not even the first one of the corpus...)

Here is my code

```
import csv
with open('twitter_test_python.csv',"r", encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile , delimiter=" ", quotechar = "'")
    for line in spamreader:
        test = list(set(line) - set(swl))
        with open("test2.csv", 'w', encoding = 'utf8') as myfile :
            wr = csv.writer(myfile)#, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, lineterminator = '\n') 
            wr.writerow([test])
```

Does someone understand my problem ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Why is there a # on the second last line?

Comment: @Muctadir, I'm going to guess that they are optional parameters for `.writer()` which he has omitted for testing, but has left there for reference or so they can be added back in later if he so chooses. I do the same thing when I debug and I am testing to see if my additional parameters are the problem.

Comment: Yes the # was for debugging my code. I took back a lot of # before posting  but I guess I did not notice this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting your file every time you go through your loop:

```
for line in spamreader():
```

Try moving the opening of the output file outside the loop:

```
import csv
with open('twitter_test_python.csv',"r", encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile , delimiter=" ", quotechar = "'")
    with open("test2.csv", 'w', encoding = 'utf8') as myfile :
        wr = csv.writer(myfile)#, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, lineterminator = '\n')
        for line in spamreader:
            test = list(set(line) - set(swl)) 
            wr.writerow([test])
```

That way you don't open the output file and overwrite it each time.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works good now ;) Indeed it was a problem with my loop.